# Want exact file format on download which we had upload for signature on document sign

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am following these steps.

1. I am uploading the files of TEXT / PNG / DOCX / PPTX for the DocuSign using 
   c# API.
2. when I download that file after the signature of the document I got PDF format of that signature document except for uploaded file format.

Is there any alternate way of code or API how I got the same extension file on the download after signature done.

**Envelope ID:- 3a6b752a-92f1-4751-b06a-ffb2c236f65d , 93409bdc-edcf-4e4b-8c6f-3c76c6305dcf , 5a32979b-3739-4585-a554-b725e1d65504**

**I am using below code in asp.net.**

```
// get Lists the envelope documents.
public static EnvelopeDocumentsResult ListEnvelopeDocuments(string accountId, string envelopeId)
{
   EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
   EnvelopeDocumentsResult docsList = envelopesApi.ListDocuments(accountId, 
   envelopeId);
   return docsList;
}
// download file using envelopeId and that I get .pdf format 

public static string DownloadSignedDocument(string envelopeId, string tempFileName, string companyCode, string apiUserName, string apiPassword, string integratorkey, string restApi)
{
  ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(restApi);
  Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;
// call the Login() API which sets the user's baseUrl and returns their accountId
string accountId = LoginApi(apiUserName, apiPassword, integratorkey);
// pass accountid and envelop id to get perticuler document for the download
  EnvelopeDocumentsResult documentList = ListEnvelopeDocuments(accountId, 
  envelopeId);

string SignedPDFPath = string.Empty;
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
foreach (EnvelopeDocument document in documentList.EnvelopeDocuments)
{
   MemoryStream docStream = 
   (MemoryStream)envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, 
    envelopeId, documentList.EnvelopeDocuments[0].DocumentId);
    string documentName = document.Name != "Summary" ? document.Name : 
    "Summary";
     SignedPDFPath = 
    systemConfiguration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uploadFolder"] + 
    "/" + companyCode + "/" + "DocuSign/" + envelopeId;
     if (!Directory.Exists(SignedPDFPath))
      {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(SignedPDFPath);
      }
      string[] tempFileExtention = tempFileName.Split('.');
      string[] removeFileExtention = documentName.Split('.');
      // need to give hardcoded ".pdf" extention because **document.Name** 
      //gives pdf file formate
      SignedPDFPath = SignedPDFPath + "/" + removeFileExtention[0] + ".pdf" 
      ;

    // Server.MapPath("~/Uploadfiles/" + recipient.EnvelopeID + "/" + 
 //  recipient.EnvelopeID + "_" + documentName + ".pdf");
     using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(SignedPDFPath))
      {
       docStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       docStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
      }
     break;
    }
     return SignedPDFPath;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

All files are converted to PDF upon upload to DocuSign. If desired, you could use external tools to convert that PDF into another file format, but you would be breaking the 'tamper evident' digital seal on the document.